# Change the font of the wordpress plug-in

Tags: wordpress

i recently purchased a plug-in for my wordpress website called "pull out widget"
I don't like the font on the plugin. Is there a way I can change the font on it and use a Google font instead. any help would be appreciated. I tried to edit the plug-in but I don't know PHP that well. And I don't wana mess up the plug-in so I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font face via your theme's custom CSS – all pullout widgets are wrapped into a div with ID #pullouts.  The custom CSS will overrule the pull-out-widget's css.

So just go into your custom css, and use Firebug or something to determine what class to call if you're unsure .... and of course this is assuming you downloaded the google fonts plugin -- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-fonts/